# I cant force a value into the "thereg" registry file

Tags: module, verilog, clock, cpu-registers, modelsim

```
module myRegister
(input clk,
input [3:0] write,
input [3:0] read1,
input [3:0] read2,
input [3:0]writedata);

reg[3:0]thereg[7:0];
reg [3:0]readdata1;
reg [3:0]readdata2;

always @(posedge clk) begin
readdata1=thereg[read1];
readdata2=thereg[read2];
end

always @(negedge clk) begin
thereg[write]=writedata;

end
endmodule
```

I need to force values (1s and 0s) into the "thereg" registry file and read from it twice on the positive edge from the clock and write from it once on the negative edge of the clock.  I am unable to force any values however.  I click force and nothing happens, however, I am able to force values into everything else.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you created a testbench to drive values rather than force them from a waveform window?

Answer (score 0):

In testbench, you will get access only to the input/output ports, but not to the wire/reg. Better way for your requirement is to force the values to input port writedata at each negative edges and you will get the same data at successive positive clock edges on the output ports readdata1 & readdata2.